# Rails sessions with redis and no database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, redis

Hi I'm currently working in this application that consumes some API to retrieve and send all the information, the API manage the database and in my side (Rails app) there is no database.

I was told to use redis to store the sessions so here I am working with redis and no databases, my models don't use ARecord nor AResource. With this in mind I'm working in a logout method but since I don't have any database I'm not sure of what is the approach I should take to handle this because the session is stored in redis and I don't know the keys of the session and also I don't know how to link that session with the user logged I have no idea of how to delete this session.

I'm open to suggestions but it has to be a redis kind of solution, there is any authentification for rails working with redis out there?

Comment: I was going to vote this down, but seeing as how it's your first question, I'll say this instead: It doesn't look like you've done any research. There's a lot of information that you can use at least as a starting point on this topic simply by searching 'rails redis sessions' on google. Also, Redis technically is a database - it's just not a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/jodosha/redis-store.

> Redis Store provides a full set of stores (*Cache*, I18n, Session, HTTP Cache) for all the modern Ruby frameworks like: Ruby on Rails, Sinatra, Rack, Rack::Cache and I18n. It natively supports object marshalling, timeouts, single or multiple nodes and namespaces.